# Why does the JNI C API use a pointer-to-pointer instead of straight pointers for JNIEnv?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, programming-languages, jnienv

***Disclaimer:** I have implemented my own object-oriented programming languages, so am familiar with (and have taught) pointers and C. Memory management 101 is not what this question is about. Neither is this about the JNI C++ API that looks similar. Thank you.*

When you look at the JNI C API for Java, in `jni.h`, `JNIEnv` is a `typedef` for a pointer to a `struct JNINativeInterface`. Given all JNI C API takes a `JNIEnv*`, this means it is really a `JNINativeInterface **`, meaning a pointer to a pointer to a `struct`.

Why does JNI use that extra level of indirection?

Simulating an object-like construct in C would work just fine with a `JNINativeInterface*`. You could just call

```
env->NewGlobalRef(env, my_object);
```

so why force us to do

```
(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, my_object);
```

? The extra level of indirection is passed into the functions as the first argument, so I guess they could update that pointer. Is that it?

**Correction:**
I had originally mis-remembered and passed `(*env)` instead of `env` as the first argument and therefore excluded the possibility of the callee editing the pointer itself. I've corrected the post. Thanks to [John Bollinger](/users/2402272/john-bollinger) for pointing that out.

Comment: From `jni.h`, there is a comment: _We use inlined functions for C++ so that programmers can write:_ `env->FindClass("java/lang/String")` _in C++ rather than:_ `(*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String")` _in C._

Comment: As the italic text at the top says, this question isn't about the C++ API.

Comment: No, but it explains _why_ it's a double pointer. They geared it for c++, and made it less nice for c.

Comment: See Dmitri Pisklov's answer (and my comments). It's actually not a double pointer (!), the public headers just make it look like one. And that C++ description seems to me to just describe a bit of syntactic sugar they _wrapped around_ the C API to make it nicer to use.

Comment: @uliwitness, when jni.h is compiled by a C compiler, the first parameter to each JNI function is a `const struct JNINativeInterface_ **` -- a double pointer indeed -- because that parameter is declared as a `JNIEnv *`, and when the header is compiled in C, `JNIEnv` is a `typedef` for `const struct JNINativeInterface_ *`.

Comment: Note, however, that your example correct call is in fact wrong.  The correct form would be `(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, my_object)`.  And perhaps that speaks somewhat to the question, because there is a mixture of levels of indirection (in the C interface) that you may not have appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JNIEnv` is not really a pointer to a pointer, but to a data structure containing other (private) thread-specific information. The `JNINativeInterface*` is just the first field in the struct, and the rest aren't public. This allows for more flexibility in VM's implementation of JNI function tables.

Some links here for the benefit of those who might come across this:

1. [Threads and JNI](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/sync.html) - here it explains:

   > The JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv *) is only valid in the current thread. You must not pass the interface pointer from one thread to another, or cache an interface pointer and use it in multiple threads. The Java Virtual Machine will pass you the same interface pointer in consecutive invocations of a native method from the same thread, but different threads pass different interface pointers to native methods.
2. [JNI spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#jni_interface_functions_and_pointers)

Comment: That seems odd though. The garbage collector runs on its own thread ... it wouldn't be safe to de-reference this pointer without a lock if it could be moved by GC. Also, having the GC relocate objects in memory seems unusual given most OSes have virtual memory these days. Do you have a link to more information?

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#jni_interface_functions_and_pointers

Comment: Regarding the threading - "The JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv *) is only valid in the current thread. You must not pass the interface pointer from one thread to another, or cache an interface pointer and use it in multiple threads. The Java Virtual Machine will pass you the same interface pointer in consecutive invocations of a native method from the same thread, but different threads pass different interface pointers to native methods." http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/sync.html

Comment: Thanks, that Oracle link helps. The illustration shows that `JNIEnv` is not really a pointer to a pointer, but a data structure containing other (private) thread-specific information. The `JNINativeInterface*` is just the first field in the `struct`, and the rest aren't public. It also explains that it is _not_ about garbage collection, but rather about being able to provide different versions of the functions:
```
The advantage to using an interface table (…) is that the JNI name space becomes separate (…) A VM can easily provide multiple versions of JNI function tables.
```

Comment: Do you want to update your answer with that information? You pointed me at the right answer, so I'd happily accept it then :D

Comment: Well it's actually both, to some extent - it also points out that each thread gets its own pointer which help garbage collection's safepointing - I'll update to reflect that.

Comment: The OP is asking about the C interface, not the C++ one.  They are absolutely right that when jni.h is processed by a C compiler, `JNIEnv` is a `typedef` for `const struct JNINativeInterface_ *`, so that the first parameter to each JNI function, which has type `JNIEnv *`, is in fact a double pointer.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: multiple factors, among them binary compatibility, multithreading support, and desired interface characteristics led to the design of the JNI and the C calling paradigm that follows from it.

### C JNI calling idiom

> so why force us to do
>
> ```
> (*env)->NewGlobalRef((*env), my_object);
> ```
>
> ? The extra level of indirection is not passed into the functions as
>   the first argument, so they can't update that pointer.

**That is not the correct form for a JNI call**.  [As the specification attests](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#native_method_arguments), and indeed as is clear(ish) from the distributed JNI header files, the correct form is

```
JNIEnv *env = /* ... */;

(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, my_object);
```

Note well that

1. In the C API, `JNIEnv` is itself a pointer type (as is necessary for applying the `->` operator to `*env`), and especially
2. It is `env` itself, not `*env`, that is passed to the JNI function.  That is, **the extra indirection *is* passed on to JNI functions**, contrary to the question's assertion.

### JNI design considerations

Having taken some time to think about it and to read some of the informative sections of [the JNI specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html), however, I have changed my mind about the design being geared specifically to make for a clean C++ interface at the the expense of a slightly less clean C interface.  The only *technical* reason why the JNI C interface would need to be designed to use the calling idiom it does would be so that JNI functions could swap out one environment for a different one, but there is no reason to think that any JNI function does this or that it was envisioned that any ever would.  (More comments about this design choice later.)

[Chapter 1 of the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html) provides as much of the official story as is available.  It discusses the historical background and design objectives for the current (second) major iteration of the JNI.  In particular, Sun's position was that a well-designed interface would have these among its advantages:

> - Each VM vendor can support a larger body of native code.
> - Tool builders will not have to maintain different kinds of native method interfaces.
> - Application programmers will be able to write one version of their native code and this version will run on different VMs.

After consultation with various interested parties, they arrived at these high-level design requirements:

> - Binary compatibility - The primary goal is binary compatibility of native method libraries across all Java VM implementations on a
>     given platform. Programmers should maintain only one version of their
>     native method libraries for a given platform.
> - Efficiency - To support time-critical code, the native method interface must impose little overhead. All known techniques to ensure
>     VM-independence (and thus binary compatibility) carry a certain amount
>     of overhead. We must somehow strike a compromise between efficiency
>     and VM-independence.
> - Functionality - The interface must expose enough Java VM internals to allow native methods to accomplish useful tasks.

The docs express considerable appreciation for COM as an interface technology that accomplishes these objectives, and indeed, Microsoft had created a COM interface to its Java 1 VM.  But of course, COM also has some problems, not only with regard to technical details *vis a vis* Java, but also with the minor matter of (non-)availability on platforms of interest, including Sun's own Solaris. Therefore, and I think this may be the true answer to the question posed:

> Although Java objects are not exposed to the native code as COM
>   objects, the JNI interface itself is binary-compatible with COM. JNI
>   uses the same jump table structure and calling convention that COM
>   does. *This means that, as soon as cross-platform support for COM is
>   available, the JNI can become a COM interface to the Java VM.*

(Emphasis in the original.)

### Final JNI design

The specification goes on to provide [a high-level description of what having a COM-congruent form means](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#jni_interface_functions_and_pointers), with a key part being:

> Native code accesses Java VM features by calling JNI functions. JNI
>   functions are available through an interface pointer. An interface
>   pointer is a pointer to a pointer. This pointer points to an array of
>   pointers, each of which points to an interface function. Every
>   interface function is at a predefined offset inside the array.

That is exactly what we in fact see, and the spec goes on to express how it is similar to both a C++ virtual function table and to a COM interface.  It also clarifies that using a function table has these advantages:

- isolating the JNI namespace from the native namespace
- allowing the same VM to provide alternative function tables in different contexts

Furthermore, it explains that providing a double pointer to the function table facilitates presenting different tables to different threads:

> The JNI interface pointer is only valid in the current thread. A
>   native method, therefore, must not pass the interface pointer from one
>   thread to another. A VM implementing the JNI may allocate and store
>   thread-local data in the area pointed to by the JNI interface pointer.
>
> Native methods receive the JNI interface pointer as an argument. The
>   VM is guaranteed to pass the same interface pointer to a native method
>   when it makes multiple calls to the native method from the same Java
>   thread. However, a native method can be called from different Java
>   threads, and therefore may receive different JNI interface pointers.

(A "JNI interface pointer" is the aforementioned double pointer, whose type is expressed in the C JNI as `JNIEnv *`.)

### Conclusion

The C calling paradigm follows directly from that data and interface design.  The JNI interface pointer must be dereferenced to get the function table pointer, and the interface pointer itself, not the function table pointer, is passed to each function.

The exact same thing happens in the C++ API, too, but it is disguised by wrapping the function table pointer in a class and disguising the JNI interface pointer as a pointer to an instance of that class.  That also provides an opportunity to provide wrapper functions that disguise the fact that the JNI interface pointer is passed to JNI functions.  I take this as good use of C++ features to provide a simple and natural interface in that language, not as evidence of a C++-first approach to designing the JNI.

Answer (score 1):

From `jni.h`, there is a comment:

> We use inlined functions for C++ so that programmers can write: `env->FindClass("java/lang/String")` in C++ rather than: `(*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String")` in C.

For example, in the `struct JNIEnv_`, if c++, there is a method:

```
jclass FindClass(const char *name) {
    return functions->FindClass(this, name);
}
```

The class has a pointer:

```
const struct JNINativeInterface_ *functions;
```

[which is the only thing visible to C]. It is a pointer to a virtual function table.

So, AFAICT, the correct deref [for C] is:

```
env->functions->FindClass(env,name)
```

This is how the member function does the call, and also matches the above cited comment.

So, are you *sure* that:

```
env->functions->FindClass(*env,name)
```

works?

It just happens that `(*env)->FindClass(env,name)` works because `functions` is the *first* element [and for C the only element].

So, for me, I'd create a macro that does the deref:

```
#define DEREF(_env) ((_env)->functions)
DEREF(env)->FindClass(env,name)
```

Comment: This is largely my evaluation, too.  The key evidence for me is in how the C++ interface leverages the equality of `this` and `&functions` in member functions of `struct JNIEnv_`.  We have a double pointer in the C interface because we (effectively) have a double pointer in the C++ interface, too, and I guess the additional indirection is useful on the C++ side -- perhaps simply to facilitate wrapping the C interface.

Comment: Note, however, that jni.h plays some games to with type definitions.  I assume this is responsible for your incorrect conclusion that the correct deref for C would be `env->functions->FindClass(env,name)`.  It is not.  In C, a `JNIEnv` *is* a `struct JNINativeInterface_ *`, just as the OP says, not a `struct JNIEnv_` (note trailing underscore) as it is in C++.  In C, then, `*env` has no member named "functions".  But the OP is also wrong: the correct C call would be `(*env)->FindClass(env, name)` (without a dereference of the first argument).

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are correct. I missed the `typedef` for `JNIEnv`. But, looking further, it seems to me that for c++: `env->FindClass(name)` _but_ for C, with `JNIEnv env = ...;`, it is `env->FindClass(&env,name)` [and _not_ `(*env)->FindClass(env,name)`] because `FindClass` [in `JNINativeInterface_`] takes `JNIEnv *` which _is_ a double pointer, but, `env` is a single pointer, so we need `&env` for the arg, but `(*env)->whatever()` would be wrong, unless there is _more_ trickery in the actual impl of `FindClass`!? Your thoughts? Other way: `JNIEnv *env = ...; (*env)->FindClass(env,name);`

Comment: The data type of the first argument to each C interface function is `JNIEnv *` (note *no* underscore), *a.k.a.* `JNINativeInterface_ **`.  This is the type of the `env` we are discussing, so (1) yes, it is a double pointer; and (2) the value received through this parameter is of course already of the correct type to pass on to other JNI functions. `(*env)->FindClass(env,name)` is the correct form, as [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#native_method_arguments) also attests.